# Adding script after woocommerce product title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display a wordpress shortcode **after** the product title on my woocommerce products page.

Does anyone know how I can do this? I have looked all over but I cannot work out where or how to input this. All I keep doing is breaking the site :(

Comment: Could you post the code here?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys but I am still a bit lost. I want to put the shortcode [voter] to show next to the woocommerce product title on my shop page and single product page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_template_single_title` hook. Example is given below.

```
add_action('woocommerce_template_single_title', 'your_function');

function your_function(){

 // Do your stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Woo Commerce doesn't have a shortcode for displaying a product name but you can easily create your own function.

```
function displayProductName($item) 
{
$productName = get_the_title($item['id']);
return $productName;
}

add_shortcode('product_name', 'displayProductName');
```

Add the above code to your functions.php file and then use [product_name id="10"] to output the product title, where id is the id of the product in question. The above example uses the get_the_title() in-built WordPress function: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/